# ClassLoader For frameworkspring 4.3 with tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, tomcat8

The problem consist some strategies!

- The project this manager dependencies  "maven" and "Sonatype Nexus"
- There are same artifact, in this case call: **core**.
- That **core** contains twos class special called SysSpringBoot and SysSpringConfig
- This one special class SysSpringConfig, it's need rewrite for last project to use this artifact.
- This artifact use for many projects, where each project that use should say which packages scan.

when start this project has one directory it's seems

--webapp

```
 -- pages .xhtml (web pages)
 -- WEB_INF 
     -- web.xml
     -- classes
        -- SysSpringConfig.class
     -- lib
        -- my-artifact-core-1.0.0.0.jar
           (in my file .jar also contains SysSpringConfig.class (old version))
```

The classLoader tomcat 8(last version, in old version not has this problem), ready first

../classes/SysSpringConfig.class, then not found all dependencies for use,
at now, find in files *.jar, but in *.jar also find SysSpringConfig.class that time ready another class with the first time!

Same suggest kind implement personality MyClassLoader to solve this problem with Spring classLoader.

*sorry with my English*